# Licensing on enterprise application

Tags: licensing, software-distribution

I am developing an enterprise application including central database, MVC web app, Mobile app client, web services and WPF client Windows service application which are working all together, I am going to make a contract with a company to grant them exclusive re-seller Representation .
So I am thinking a way to control the number of sales and provide them a license key for each sale to they could use the key in installation or other step and I want to get informed by the application whenever it is installing somewhere and want to prevent working when the license is used once or is expired or something. I need a solution from people who have same successful experience in this matter, indeed I have some ideas but actually I am not experienced in this issue and I'll be so happy to hear good approaches on this.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to choose your preferred licensing system. A small list is available in the [Question about OS Licensing Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639571/what-open-source-license-verification-frameworks-are-there/14771485#14771485). Second you'll need some kind of service where your reseller can issue licenses without real access to your private license key. E.g. some kind of webservice.

Then you'll have the number of licenses that your reseller has created and you can bill him.
If you also want to know which licenses was activated you can implement some kind of "phone home" in your application.